# Generate ClientId/ClientSecret in Salesforce for external application to connect

Tags: remote-access, winter15, client-id

I am attempting to recreate the sample console application found at
https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/tree/master/samples/SimpleConsole.

This also leverages the NUGET package https://www.nuget.org/packages/DeveloperForce.Force/.

Everything seems pretty straightforward and I have a username/password.

Where things fall apart is that I need to get a clientid/clientsecret setup in my Salesforce sandbox.  The documentation says to go to `Setup` > `Develop` > `Remote Access` and create a new entry.  From that you will get the needed values.

However Since Winter '15 was released, `Remote Access` now goes to `Create` > `Apps`.  From what I can read and see, there isn't a place for me to get the clientid/clientsecret.

What do I have to do in Winter '15 to get a clientid/clientsecret?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have created a connected app at the bottom of the "Apps" page, do not click on "Edit" or "Manage" but instead click on the connected app name which is a hyperlink. That "Connected App Name" page will show the "Consumer Key" and the "Consumer Secret" (once you click on "Click to reveal" link).

Comment: Do I need to check 'Enable OAuth Settings' and if so, what do I use for a 'callback url' when I don't have one (console app)?

Comment: @JasonW Yes. You can add a fake callback URL such as "https://fake.com".